# How to make a function that makes each sentence in a paragraph occupy one line?

Tags: emacs, paragraph, sentence

I use emacs for my creative writing. To better analyze the structure of my sentences I would like to see  my paragraphs displayed as consisting of one sentence per line. So I need a function that can take a normal auto-filled paragraph and do the following: 1) stretches all sentences into one line, and 2) put only one sentence per line.

Imagine I had written the following paragraph (lyrics from Suzanne Vega)

> My name is Luka. I live on the second floor. I live upstairs from you.  Yes I think you've seen me before. If you hear something late at night.  Some kind of trouble. Some kind of fight.

With the function I want the paragraph would appear like this:

> My name is Luka.
>   I live on the second floor.
>   I live upstairs from you.
>   Yes I think you've seen me before.
>   If you hear something late at night.
>   Some kind of trouble.
>   Some kind of fight.

Since I would like to do some of the writing when the sentences are displayed like this, the function should in addition to stretching out the sentences also turn off the autofill mode.

Ideally I would like a function that can toggle the display between auto-fill mode with all sentences wrapped, and this new mode with auto-fill turned off and all sentences stretched out.

Thanks in advance to all sort of suggestions or help to make such a function!

@Drew: Here is a text I am not able to split up with your code:

There are two ways to enable it: the first is with M-x visual-line-mode (for those with real menus, apparently Options->Line Wrapping in this Buffer->Word Wrap), which will give you a minor mode “wrap” in the mode line. As explained in C-h f visual-line-mode, one of the effects of this command is to subtly change the effect of commands that deal with “lines”: C-a, C-e no longer go to the end of the line (as in \n), but go to the end of the line (as in display line). M-a, M-e still work as they should. In addition, vertical split windows are guaranteed to not be truncated, and resize properly on changing width. Works wonderfully, especially if you have free form text that you’re keeping in version control (like a thesis in Latex) where hard-wrapping just doesn’t work out very well. It also makes vertical splitting much more useful, especially with huge windows. In my experience, it slows down redraw a little bit, but it’s worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess something like this is what you're asking for.

```el
(defun split-para-at-sentence-ends ()
  "Split current paragraph into lines with one sentence each.
Then turn off `auto-fill-mode'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((mode  major-mode))
    (unwind-protect
         (progn (text-mode)
                (save-excursion
                  (let ((emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column  t)
                        (fill-column                       (point-max)))
                    (fill-paragraph))
                  (let ((bop  (copy-marker (progn (backward-paragraph) (point))))
                        (eop  (copy-marker (progn (forward-paragraph)  (point)))))
                    (goto-char bop)
                    (while (< (point) eop)
                      (forward-sentence)
                      (forward-whitespace 1)
                      (unless (>= (point) eop)
                        (delete-horizontal-space)
                        (insert "\n"))))))
      (funcall mode)))
  (auto-fill-mode -1))

(define-minor-mode split-para-mode 
    "Toggle between a filled paragraph and one split into sentences."
  nil nil nil
  (if (not split-para-mode)
      (split-para-at-sentence-ends)
    (auto-fill-mode 1)
    (fill-paragraph)))

(global-set-key "\C-o" 'split-para-mode) ; Or some other key.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it seems to function only partially. I will try to systematize that observation. soon back. It seems to work only if the sentences are not too long. In many cases it only makes the paragraphs much wider.

Comment: Please provide a test case, including whatever modes you might be using.

Comment: I am using Wrap mode, set by the following line in my init file

(setq fill-column 100), can this mode interfere with the your code above? I have added a text (from an emacs web page) that I am not able to split up with your code.

Comment: No, changing the `fill-column` should not make any difference.

Comment: Your example works for me. You don't show or point to the code for your "Wrap" mode, and you don't specify what other modes (e.g. `visual-line-mode`) you are using. Debugging that is beyond the scope of this question. If you try the answer starting from `emacs -Q` you should see that it works. If you have other code (e.g. "Wrap" mode) that interferes, you will need to accommodate that as needed. (FWIW, it works with or without `visual-line-mode` turned on, for me.)

Comment: You also do not say *what happens* when your lines are "too long". Did you try hitting `C-o` (or whatever key you've bound) twice in a row, to toggle the mode?

Comment: The code works when I insert two spaces after each period that ends a sentence. Does this makes sense based on how you have made your code?

Comment: It works for me with either one or two spaces after a sentence. But you need to customize option **`sentence-end-double-space`** accordingly. That is not particular to this code - you need to do that for any use of sentence commands in English. (I use a non-nil value for the option. But the code here works with a nil value also.)

Comment: Thanks for your advise. twocomments. 1) If I use your code on several marked paragraphs at a time, only the first will be affected. How can the code affect more than one paragraph in one go? 2) If I have starred headings (org mode) the paragraph collapses to the headline if I use your code.

Comment: @myotis To further tweaking see values of forward-paragraph, paragraph-start, paragraph-end.

Comment: This code works great in text mode!  I'm interested in modifying it to also work nicely for LaTeX documents (where, e.g., it fails to respect comments).  Any hints where I should start looking for how to do this?